# Regex: insert function with itself and arguments and add newline with same parameters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, vba

I have a question regarding Regex in Python 3:
I am using Python in order to manipulate code in VBA modules.
I want to write a Python programm so I can "collect" the inputs in my VBA submodules as follows:

The text looks something like this right now and can be regarded as a String:

```
Call myfunction1(1,2,3)
Call myfunction2(4,5,6)
```

I need a regex that inserts a newline and adds my collector function with the same inputs, resulting in something like this, without overwriting any strings:

```
Call myfunction1(1,2,3)
Call Collector(1,2,3)
Call myfunction2(4,5,6)
Call Collector(4,5,6)
```

The collector is just a VBA sub which collects my inputs.
How do I use regex so I can add the newline with the collector and keep the original input string in between?

I would be very happy for answers!

Comment: On first glance it is not clear what the regex shall match (is `myfunction` fixed or variable?) and why do you think a regex is the best solution in the first place. Place try to better describe your goal, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: myfunction is fixed. I want the regex to look for the keyword "Call myfunction" and write additionally "Call Collector"  with the inputs of myfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a simple way to do this:

```
def convert(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^Call myfunction\d+(\(.*\))$')
    result = []
    for line in s.splitlines():
        match = re.match(pattern, line)
        result.append(line)
        if match:
            result.append(f'Call Collector{match.group(1)}')
    return '\r\n'.join(result)
```

You may adapt the regex if you have more or less strict requirements for your function calls (like more spaces, comments etc.). This assumes that you have a line with only that function call, the function name is ending with an arbitrary number, and anything between the parentheses is considered the parameters and copied over to the `Collect` function.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I really appreciate your help